# more command behavior

Tags: exit, more

Someone can explain me about the more command?

when I use it with `||` or with `&&`, it seems to have an exist status of true, even when the file is not found(Unlike the other commands).

```
~/Desktop$ more notExists || echo aaa
notExists: No such file or directory
~/Desktop$ more notExists && echo aaa
notExists: No such file or directory
aaa
```

Comment: You should report it as a bug at util-linux@vger.kernel.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `more` is different on OSX and Linux. Run this to see what the return value is on your flavor of Unix:

```
more file_that_doesnt_exist; echo $?
```

On OSX, I get `1` on failure and `0` on success.

On Ubuntu and RedHat Linux, I get `0` on failure and `0` on success. This would seem to be a bug.

Another alternative would be to use `less`. It seems to return correct exit codes in Ubuntu Linux.

Yet another alternative would be to use:

```
{ cat file_that_doesnt_exist || echo nonexistent; } | more
```

The `cat` command seems to return expected exit codes in Linux.

Comment: 0 is true ?....

Comment: I just curious to know why it's always returns the same value even when the command fails (on ubuntu/sentOS)

Comment: Just a note, on OSX, [more](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/more.1.html) is most likely just a link to _less_, whereas on Linux I actually have _more_ from the _util-linux_ package...

Comment: "For the shell’s purposes, a command which exits with a zero exit status has succeeded. A non-zero exit status indicates failure. This seemingly counter-intuitive scheme is used so there is one well-defined way to indicate success and a variety of ways to indicate various failure modes. When a command terminates on a fatal signal whose number is N, Bash uses the value 128+N as the exit status." (from http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Exit-Status)